# render() method isn't always called when state changes? (Weird behaviour in react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch-api

I'm learning react and trying to code soccer standings of top 5 leagues by using football-data API but there is a strange problem.

I read that every time the state is changed, `render()` is called. In my code, `render()` isn't called after fetching data from API.

The method `getAllStandings()` is called at the beginning and for each `competitionId` of the `competitionsIds` array, it fetches the standing. After iterating every id, the state is updated and the `render()` method should be called but it doesn't. The variables in the `render()` method are empty.

Maybe it is due to the async function?

Here is my code (`getAllStandings()` is called in the `componentDidMount()` method):

```
  getAllStandings(){
    let list = [];
    let competitions = this.state.competitionsIds; // [1,2,3,4,5]
    console.log("Competitions: ", competitions);
    competitions.forEach((item, i) => {
      this.getStandingById(item).then((data) => list.push(data));
    });

    this.setState({
      standingsList: list
    },() => console.log("standingsList: ", this.state.standingsList));
  }

  async getStandingById(competitionId) {
    //console.log("Fetching standing of competition with id: ", competitionId);
    const url = this.state.url.concat("competitions/").concat(competitionId).concat("/standings/");

    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'X-Auth-Token': this.state.auth
      }
    };

    let response = await fetch(url, options);
    let data = await response.json();
    return await data;

  }


  render() {
    let standingsArr = this.state.standingsList;
    console.log("standingsArr: ", JSON.stringify(standingsArr));
    console.log("length: ", standingsArr.length);

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>{this.state.standingsList.map((item) => (
          <TableComp name="yes"/>
        ))}</div>
      </div>
    );

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not handling the asynchronous operations correctly.

```js
let list = [];
console.log("Competitions: ", competitions);
competitions.forEach((item, i) => {
  this.getStandingById(item).then((data) => list.push(data));
});

this.setState({
  standingsList: list
},() => console.log("standingsList: ", this.state.standingsList));
```

The `forEach` will finish before all of the calls to `getStandingById` are completed, so your `list` will not have all the data you want.  You need to wait for all of those calls to complete before calling `setState`. Collecting them all in an array and using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) could do the trick:

```js
let list = [];
console.log("Competitions: ", competitions);
const promises = [];
competitions.forEach((item) => {
  const promise = this.getStandingById(item).then((data) => list.push(data));
  promises.push(promise);
});

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  this.setState({
    standingsList: list
  });
});
```

Note that the order the data is pushed to `list` will not be the same every time. If the order is important, then don't use `forEach` since they'll all get kicked off in parallel. Instead you could use a normal `for` loop and `await` each call to `getStandingById` before continuing to the next competition like this:

```js
async getAllStandings() {
  let list = [];
  console.log("Competitions: ", competitions);
  for (const item of competitions) {
    // do them sequentially to preserve order
    await this.getStandingById(item).then((data) => list.push(data));
  });

  this.setState({
    standingsList: list
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your getStandingById function, your forEach will end before the setState is called, so you need to wait for the results of your promises, you can do that using a map wrapped in a Promise.all, notice that I changed the getAllStandings to an async function.

```
async getAllStandings(){
    let competitions = this.state.competitionsIds; // [1,2,3,4,5]
    console.log("Competitions: ", competitions);
    const list = await Promise.all(competitions.map((item, i) => {
      return this.getStandingById(item);
    }));

    this.setState({
      standingsList: list
    },() => console.log("standingsList: ", this.state.standingsList));
  }
```